# why my data lose it's dimension when I use lapply?

Tags: r

I'm reading lot's of files from directory and doing some computation on each file.
because I want to make my script parralel, I use lapply. when I look at the dimention of my data frame at each element of list, it's become 1. 
would someone help me to fix it ?
Here is my effort :

```
 files <- list.files(path="path to file") 
 dfr <- lapply(files, function(x) read.table(x,header=T,sep="\n"))


            for(i in drf){
             Do some computation

                if (ncol(i) > 1){

            y <- as.matrix(i[1])
            x <- as.matrix(i[2:ncol(i)])
            }
    .
    .

    }

        # 

            > i
            [[1]]
               ACAA2.hsa.miR.124.AGO2.hsa.miR.124.AGO134
            1        7.6561 18.5924339201 23.4560035028 
            2        7.2355 26.2524888635 33.6513700944 
            3         7.365 23.6841865928 28.2168475593 
            4        8.4768 22.4003094419 28.0983702155 
            5        5.5838 20.4838449736 26.8616064228 
            6        7.3123 20.8488005184 26.9155966811 
            7        7.2345 21.5272944711 26.2954400309 
            8          7.05 23.3113502366 29.3856555269 
> dim(i[1])
NULL
> dim(i[[1]])
[1] 67  1
      > a<-i[[1]]
> dim(a)
[1] 67  1
> a
   ACAA2.hsa.miR.124.AGO2.hsa.miR.124.AGO134
1        7.6561 18.5924339201 23.4560035028 
2        7.2355 26.2524888635 33.6513700944 
3         7.365 23.6841865928 28.2168475593 
4        8.4768 22.4003094419 28.0983702155 
5        5.5838 20.4838449736 26.8616064228 
6        7.3123 20.8488005184 26.915596681

    but I would expect 

        >dim(a)
         67  3

    Because I loses the dimension of data, my *for loop* doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is not the `for` loop or the `lapply` call but your `read.table` command. You use `sep="\n"` instead of `sep=" "`.

`?read.table` shows you that the `sep` argument is the field separator. It seems your field separator is a space `" "`. Just use `read.table` without specifying the `sep` argument should work.